# Gimp: fill cut out photo with photos (2 layer photos)

Tags: gimp, layers, photo-editing

I want to cut some part of my image and, in the exact place of the cut out portion, place another photo. The image has some text inside, but instead of text place a part of another image.

I tried different things for 2 hours with no success. I don't know what it's called and wasn't able to find it with google. How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that you don't need to cut both photos, you cut only the top one. You don't care what is below the text on the bottom photo since it will be masked. So:

- *File>Open* and load the first image (background image)
- *File>Open as layers* and load the second image (that will be cut after the text)
- *Layer>Transparency>Add alpha channel*
- Open the Layers list (Ctr-L): you should see your two pictures. The name of the top one should not be in boldface.
- Start the Text tool and add the text you want (this creates a third layer)
- With that text layer still selected in the Layers list: *Layer>Transparency>Alpha to selection*: you should see "marching ants" alon the outline of the text
- In the Layers list:

  - Make the Text layer invisible (click on the eye icon next to it)
  - Make the text image  active by clicking on it
- Invert the selection: *Select>Invert* (the "marching ants" stay the same, but the selection is on the other side, since now what is selected is everything but the text shape)
- *Edit>Clear* or [delete] and your top image should now be cut following the text shape.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably need to look for tutorials that cover the use of layers and layer masks.  These are the kind of techniques that are used for such edits in software such as GIMP or Photoshop.  There are plenty tutorials for this on youtube if you search.

Here's an example, showing a layer mask made of text, to mask out parts of another photo - in essence the photo appears inside the text.

[image: Example using Layer Masks in GIMP]